# ASP.NET MVC : could not find endpoint element with name contract

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I had created an MVC application that had no authentication so I was advised to create a mvc project that has the 'Individual User Accounts' option selected which brings with it some controllers, models and views.

What I had done to keep my old class library data was rename the current class library as Projectold in my file explorer and created a new class library in Visual Studio with the same name(Project) then imported all the controllers, views, config files that I had from my previous library and included them in the new class library.

I have a proxy to 2 web services that exposes data for me to use. Because I only needed a new class library, I had the existing <system.serviceModel> tag already there in the existing service folder so I just copied and pasted it within the new web.config file in the new class library.

What has happened is that now I cannot access the web service to access the data. I am thrown the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=Could not find endpoint element with name 'WebServiceSoap' and contract 
'ProxyToWebService.WebServiceSoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration 
section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no 
endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.
Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

My web.config file is (The proxy URL's have been anonymised):

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WebServiceSoap"/>
            <binding name="SWebServiceSoap"/>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="WebServiceSoap12">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12"/>
                <httpTransport/>
            </binding>
            <binding name="SWebServiceSoap12">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12"/>
                <httpTransport/>
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
  <endpoint address="http://URL/URL/URL.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebServiceSoap" contract="ProxyToWebService.WebServiceSoap" name="WebServiceSoap" />
  <endpoint address="http://URL/URL/URL.asmx" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebServiceSoap12" contract="ProxyToWebService.WebServiceSoap" name="WebServiceSoap12" />
  <endpoint address="http://URL/URL/URL.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SWebServiceSoap" contract="ProxyToSWebService.SWebServiceSoap" name="SWebServiceSoap" />
  <endpoint address="http://URL/URL/URL.asmx" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SWebServiceSoap12" contract="ProxyToSWebService.SWebServiceSoap" name="SWebServiceSoap12" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I have returned to a back up copy and it works before I replace my old new class library with my new class library so the endpoint connections should be okay. Just when they are used in the new class library is where it breaks.
I cannot just copy the old web.config file either as because the Individual User Accounts option is selected, it has modified the web.config file.

My code for the proxy connection:

```
        public InboundService()
    {
        proxy = new WebServiceSoapClient("WebServiceSoap", "http://URL/URL/URL.asmx");
        Sproxy = new SWebServiceSoapClient("SWebServiceSoap", "http://URL/URL/URL.asmx");
    }
```

Comment: Where is your web.config file? inside class library or inside web project ?

Comment: @Amir Sorry for not being clear, the web.config file is in the class library. Essentially, I had 6 projects in the solution, I only needed to remove the main class library and replace it with a new one that has the Individual User Accounts option selected.

Comment: Do you have another web.config file inside your web project (that the corresponding class library is added to) ?

Comment: @Amir There is a web.config file for my web services but these are not used in this case as that is regarding exposing my data to others as a web service. In this scenario, I am only using the 1 web.config file and that is located in the class library.

Comment: just move to config file from the class library to web project or make this web.config file (copy-local):
right click on the file and make the copy-local property of it to true.